# RxJava combining Observables for more than one request

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I have some problems in my rx vs retrofit architecture.

I have `Observable<SignUpServerCode> signUp(@Body AccountSignUpRequest signUpRequest)` that makes request to server for registration. Server return me `SignUpServerCode` in which I have parameter `code` if it == `200` I make request for authorization  `Observable<LoginServerCode> logIn(@Body AccountLogInRequest logInRequest);` which returns me `LoginServerCode`. I am new in rx and I dont understand how can I combine this 2 observable request in one.

My task make registration request, filter result and if it success make another request for login, at the end I should have `LoginServerCode`

At the moment I have only registration request, how to add authorization  requst in it?

```
Observable<SignUpServerCode> signUp = networkBaseService.signUp(model.getSignUpRequest());
        signUp.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<SignUpServerCode>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(SignUpServerCode signUpServerCode) {

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You would flatmap the signUp call/observable into an observable that emits the results of your login call. Then you could subscribe as you already are.

Answer (score 0):

**My solution:**

```
 Observable<SignUpServerCode> signUp = networkBaseService.signUp(model.getSignUpRequest());
        signUp.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .filter(element -> element.account_signup.code == 200 ? true : false)
                .map(element -> createLoginRequest())
                .flatMap(loginRequest -> logIn(loginRequest))
                .filter(element -> element.account_login.code == 200 ? true : false)
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<LoginServerCode>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(LoginServerCode loginServerCode) {
                    }
                });

private Observable<LoginServerCode> logIn(LogInRequest request){
        return  networkBaseService.logIn(request).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }
```